# Android compose test TextField input type

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing, android-compose-textfield

How would you go about testing what input type TextField uses, for example if I wanted to test if user input has an alphanumeric keyboard type or numeric.

I can see that in SemanticProperties there is ImeAction, but I can't see anything I could use to check KeyboardOptions that you set in TextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
    val platformTextInputService = mock<PlatformTextInputService>()
    val textInputService = TextInputService(platformTextInputService)
    composeRule.setContent {

        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalTextInputService provides textInputService
        ) {
            val text = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            TextField(
                modifier = Modifier.testTag(TextfieldTag),
                value = text.value,
                onValueChange = { text.value = it },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number
                )
            )
        }
    }


    composeRule.onNodeWithTag(TextfieldTag).performClick()

    composeRule.runOnIdle {
        verify(platformTextInputService, atLeastOnce()).startInput(
            value = any(),
            imeOptions = eq(
                ImeOptions(
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                )
            ),
            onEditCommand = any(),
            onImeActionPerformed = any()
        )
    }
```